# Список шрифтов в системе

Tags: javascript, шрифты

Доброго времени суток! можно ли получить список шрифтов, доступных в системе, средствами javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Ну поиск говорит о двух рабочих способах: [flash](http://hasseg.org/blog/post/526/getting-a-list-of-installed-fonts-with-flash-and-javascript/) и [перебор](http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/).

Answer (score 0):

- Может это подойдет? [JavaScript/CSS Font Detector](http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/)
- Вот еще вариант: [Javascript: проверка установленного шрифта](http://jurius.name/work/javascript/javascript-proverka-ustanovlennogo-shrifta.html)

А может по такому пути пойти — использовать веб-шрифты?! [Ссылка на вопрос #ХэшКод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/222372/%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-segoe-ui-light).