# Аналоги Segoe UI light

Tags: веб-дизайн, шрифты

Нашёл хороший шрифт от майкрософта - Segoe UI light. Увы от толе вообще платных, толе просто разрешается использовать только на вин. А мне бы хотелось влепить на сайт что-нибудь такое похожие, но 'без ограничений'. Подскажите?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Тут описано](http://habrahabr.ru/post/64596/) как обеспечить подгрузку шрифта с сайта, чтобы его было видно даже тем, у кого его нет. 
   Хак: если у вас есть какой-либо пакет от мелкомягких, то обращаемся в папку "fonts". :)
2. Шрифт Segoe делала конторка Monotype. На fonts.com есть доступ к бесплатному использованию для веба. Ссылки: [Segoe TV Family](http://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/segoe-tv?QueryFontType=Web#product_top), [Segoe Print Family](http://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/segoe-print?QueryFontType=Web#product_top), [Segoe Script Family](http://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/segoe-script?QueryFontType=Web#product_top), [Segoe Mono Family](http://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/segoe-mono?QueryFontType=Web#product_top).
3. Аналоги: [Gill Sans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gill_Sans), [Optima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optima) и другие гуманистические гротески.
4. Тут еще посмотрите, адобовская примочка: [Adobe Edge Web Fonts](https://edgewebfonts.adobe.com/fonts). И вот тут: [google search](https://www.google.ru/search?q=humanist+sans-serif+typeface&oq=huma&aqs=chrome.1.57j59j0j5j62l2.4721j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).
5. Забыл еще одну штуку: [typekit](http://html.adobe.com/edge/typekit/).

Ну вроде всё. Дальше сами. :)

Comment: Спасибо. Explain есть explain.

Answer (score 1):

На него похожи Fira Sans Light, Calibri Light, Open Sans Light. Несложно найти аналог.